# What is the magnitude and direction of the Resultant Force?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

[image: Diagram]

Find the magnitude and direction of the resultant force in Red. One displacement is of $26km$ on a bearing of $175°$ and another one is $18km$ of a bearing of $294°$.

The bottom right angle of the triangle is $61°$, so I use cosine rule:

$R^2=26^2+18^2-(26)(18)cos(61)$

$R=27.8km$

Now to work out the direction using the sine rule:

$\dfrac{sin(x)}{18}=\dfrac{sin(61)}{27.8}$

$x=34.5°$

$175+34.5=209.5°$

Now, according to my book this is wrong, the actual values are:

$23.4km$

$217.3°$

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake using cosine law, it is :
$$
C^2 = A^2 + B^2 - \color{Red}{2}AB\cos{\theta}. 
$$

If $\theta = 61^{\circ}$, $A = 26km$ and $B = 18km$, then
$$
C = \sqrt{26^2 + 18^2 - \color{Red}{2}(26)(18)\cos{61^{\circ}}}km = 23.37km \approx \boxed{23.4km}.
$$

For that, using sine law
$$
\frac{\sin{\alpha}}{B} = \frac{\sin{\theta}}{C},
$$
you get
$$
\alpha = \arcsin{\left(\frac{18}{23.4}\sin{61^{\circ}}\right)} = 42.28^{\circ} \approx 42.3^{\circ}.
$$

The total angle is $175^{\circ} + 42.3^{\circ} = \boxed{217.3^{\circ}}.$